# Game center and my own server

Tags: ios, game-center

I am creating a new online 2 player game. I already have a server with tons of players on it because of my other games. Is it possible to have one player from Game Center and another player from my own server? Or are Game Center players stuck with other Game center players? I need this relations in my game:

a Game center player -> play with another player from my own server

my own server player -> play with another player on my own server

a Game center player -> play with another Game center player

is this possible with Game center or not?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4456/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server). This will definitely help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right it should be possible. Not natively by the game-center, because the game-center is a closed network, but by implementing a second connection in addition to the game-center connection to your own server. 
This way the IOS users could easily interact and play with users on your server, as well as with users in the game-center.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean I want when a Game Center player wanna to play, I search for a player in game center and if Game Center didn't suggest any in 10 secs, I search for Player on my own server and suggest him to the current player. But as I saw Game center pops up for choosing another player and I can not suggest any player on that default page. Am I right? Or let me ask in another way: can I check this if any another player is ready on Game Center without that presented view controller of Game Center for finding another Player?